# I have moved my C# app to a server without internet access. When I open the app in this server I get several errors for missing packages. Why?

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I have a C# console app on my laptop that has internet access. When I add a nugget package, all the related additional packages are installed automatically from the internet.

But in this case I have following problem:

I have created my project with VS2022 and added the nuget packages. The project can be rebuiled without error.

Later I had to move this project from my laptop to a server, that has no internet access.
When I opened the project again with VS2022 I see that there are a lot of missing packages. I have tried to download the nupkg files from the internet and load them manualy one by one, but with each new package the system requires more missing packages, and I get more and more Errors.

How can I overcome this problem? Is it not possible to transfer all the required packages for the project, while moving the project directory?

My biggest challange is that there is no internet access on the server.

I want to be able to debug my app on the server side.

The packages that are complete on my laptop are:

[image]

The packages that are seen on the server side are:

[image]

And here the errors:

[image]

Comment: Is it because of security reasons you won't have Internet on the machine

Comment: @Maytham Fahmi Yes company restriction

Comment: Shouldn't you only have a deployed package on the server and not try to build it there? Presumably creating a deploy build would include the required dependency assemblies.

Comment: Your company policy means that you cannot build the project on that server. Either build it on a different PC and just deploy the built application - or inform your company that their policy prevents you from building it.

Comment: You'll have to setup a package repository with all these packages somewhere that the server can access.

Comment: See [Package Source Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping) for details on how to point NuGet to a different source other than the default internet URLs. You can point the server at a different machine which has the NuGet packages. Wouldn't surprise me if your company policy for the server prevented that too, though...

Comment: I have copied the nupkg files to the server, and then installed them with the nuget package manager from a local source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a self-contained deployment.

The release deployment, by default, relies on the pre-installed dotnet framework runtime.

Try to generate your bundle using the `self-contained deployment`

> dotnet build --configuration Release --self-contained

For additional information, refer to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156